# I want to hit various URLS with different users using Loadrunner. How to proceed?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have the following requirement to be done using Loadrunner. Need your thoughts, ideas..please.

Scenario: 1000 users randomly accessing a predefined list of 100 URLs (just hitting the urls). This is a public facing website and has not authentication for the users.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"public facing website "

Is it one that you own, manage or have written permission to conduct this action on?

Comment: Yes I own, manage and have all permissions to do these actions @James Pulley.

Comment: see training material on parameterization